# excel file to delimited dat file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading an excel document as below:

```
package com.sample.file;

//necessary imports goes here

public class ExcelReader { 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 

  String fname = "C:\\myExcel.xls"; // or  "C:\\myExcel.xlsx"  
  InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(fname); 
  Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp); 
  Sheet sheet = null; 

  sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 

  Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator(); 

  while (rows.hasNext()) 
    { 
            Row row = (Row) rows.next(); 

            // how to write to a semicolon delimited dat file here
    }

  inp.close(); 
} 
}
```

As seen above, I am able to read the row. However, now I want to write that row into a semicolon delimited dat file.

Also, if a column is empty, it should go as an empty value in the file i.e. no data between consecutive semicolons.

Comment: You have to do something like HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow((short) 0); HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
cellA1.setCellValue("Hello");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
while (rows.hasNext()) {
    Row row = (Row) rows.next(); 
    // how to write to a semicolon delimited dat file here
    Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();

     while (cells.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cells.next();
        sb.append(cell.toString()).append(";");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
}   

File file = new File("someFile.dat");

if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(sb.toString());
bw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming 'row.toString` return some string
add 'row.toString' to stringbuilder, semicolon separated

then after your while loop

```
            File file = new File("filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content.toString); //content is your stringbuilder
            bw.close();
```

Comment: I want to write the columns in the row I got into semicolon delimited file. For e.g. the row I got consists of 10 columns, then the line in the dat file will have 10 values delimited by semicolons.

Comment: ok, from row you can get cellIterator and then by iterating over these cells you can fetch data in them add that data into stringbuilder, append semicolon and once done write to file